# MS Access: How can I set a form Unbound Object control (bitmap) to another Bound Object on the form?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a Multiple Item form where the rows contain an image provided by a bound object control. I can't use an image object as this is one of the (very many annoying) restrictions of multiple item forms.

In the header I have a larger unbound object control (bitmap) and I would like to set its image to be the same as one in the rows when it is clicked on. As a kludge I tried using the clipboard:

```
If Screen.ActiveControl.OLEType = acOLENone Then
    Me!LargeImage.Visible = False
Else
    Screen.ActiveControl.Action = acOLECopy
    Me!LargeImage.Action = acOLEPaste
    Me!LargeImage.Visible = True
End If
```

But `Me!LargeImage.Action = acOLEPaste` fails with an error saying the action cannot be performed.

Comment: Why not change image control source property?

Comment: A form in Continuous View (Multiple Items) can definitely have an Image control. I have never used OLEObjectFrame controls, always Image control. Think I have seen code that extracts file from OLE field to clipboard but not finding it again. Closest I can find is http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm.

Comment: I had read on a different site that Image controls don't work in Multiple Item forms (I guess the name changed to Continuous View sometime after Access 2010) - I will use an Image control. They are much better as it saves wasting space with bitmaps. Also my select was having to do an Inner Join, because part of the select needed Select Distinct and the bitmap is not allowed in that. A text string for the location of the image is much better. -- I'll leave the question open as it is still a valid question.

Comment: Works a treat,. The onClick for the image cannot use Screen.ActiveControl as the image does not become an active control when clicked on. However I had a TextBox control that made sense for a click to change the image, so I used that. Also referencing `Screen.ActiveControl.Parent!SmallImage.Picture` was null so I added a hidden TextBox on the row, and stored the source path in that.

Comment: Are you saving pictures in your db as oleobjets and would like to show in a continuous form?